WooCommerce REST API does not show all the products
I have a webshop with products in 4 languages. When I try to receive the full list of products, I do not see all the products. Only the products in the Dutch language (the 'main' language) and not the products that are not published yet.
The code:
  Clear-Host
  $ConsumerKey            = "ck_blablahalblah"
  $CustomerKey            = "cs_somethingelse"
  $URL                    = "https://www.mywebshopurl.nl"
  $Products               = "/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
  $URL                    = "$($url)$($Products)"
  $Headers                = @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $ConsumerKey, $CustomerKey))) }
  [Int]$Page              = 1
  [Int]$PerPage           = 10
  $ArrayWithProducts      = @()
  Do
   {
    Write-Host "Reading products from page: $Page"
    $AllProducts       = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$($URL)?page=$Page&per_page=$PerPage&status=any&orderby=id&order=asc&catalog_visibility=any" -Headers $Headers
    Write-Host "  -->> Counted $($AllProducts.Count) products on page $Page."
  
    If (-not $AllProducts) {Break}
    $ArrayWithProducts += $AllProducts

    $Page++
   } While ($True)
    
   Write-Host "There are total $($ArrayWithProducts.Count) products discovered by the REST API."

I only see 149 products. That are 147 published products and 2 draft products. But I do not see:

All the items that already have been imported but not published yet. The status is 'Draft'.
All the with WPML translated products.

As a reference I already checked WooCommerce Rest API not returning Products and woocommerce rest api - did not show product list. I also checked https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#product-properties.
What can I do to solve points one and two.
Feedback is appreciated and with kind regards,
TheStingPilot

I don't see catalog_visibility as an accepted parameter on that endpoint, just as a product property https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-products

That is correct, I found it in some other fora. Now, I do not use the parameter anymore.
